# iOS 7 in iPad eliminate x2 button for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

I am new here. I have an iOS 6.1 iPhone application. When I try to run it in iPad running iOS 7, [the x2 zoom button at the right corner is gone](http://www.versluis.com/2013/09/ios-7-has-arrived-and-heres-what-it-does/) and my iPhone application UI mess up with the wrong position. The UIWebView is stretched over size for iPad. How can I solve this problem? Should I change it manually?

Comment: That's not something you have any control of I'm afraid.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you set the App to be Universal and only provide a Storyboard for iPhone/iPod. Then, of course, iPad tries to use the iPhone Storyboard to display the App on the full size, without the 2x button. If that's the case: Just set the App to be iPhone/iPod only.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment seems to be the actual answer, I post it again as an answer.

Setting the App to be an Universal App and only providing a Storyboard for iPhone/iPod will result in this behavior. The iPad tries to use the iPhone Storyboard to display the App on the whole screen in full size without the 2x button. Thus all elements in the App will be positioned according to their positions defined for iPhone size display.

The solution here is to set the App available for iPhone only (in App target > Deployment info > Devices > [select `iPhone` here]) instead of `Universal`. This will result in the iPad to display the App on iPhone size and provide the 2x button to zoom in.

Comment: No. I set my Devices as iPhone, my iPad's 2x button is still missing.

Comment: @Raptor Have you got 2x button in iPad?\

Comment: Seems this is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420295/missing-2x-button-with-an-iphone-app-running-on-ipad)