# Missing "2x" button with an iPhone app running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone

We developped an iPhone only app (not Universal), using Xcode 5.1, and when running on iPad, the "*2x*" button is missing, app starting in "*2x*" mode. How can that happen ? I thought when you run an iPhone app on iPad, there is always the "*2x*" button...

**EDIT**: We do our test on real non retina iPad Mini under iOS 7.

Comment: because iPad (with iOS7+) runs the iPhone apps in retina-mode only, as the iOS7 does not support non-retina iPhones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @holex for your comments.

We did more tests on iOS 7 iPad retina / non retina and found out :

- on iPad retina: your *iPhone only* app starts in *2x* mode and a *2x* button is present
- on iPad non retina: your *iPhone only* app starts in *2x* mode and **no** *2x* button is present